# How to get rotation matrix elements from root integer notation?

Tags: geometry, supercell, cell-optimization

For example, I am reading a paper, where they put one layer on top of another, and in order to minimize the lattice mismatch, they transform unit cells of both layers.

They report it in a root integer notation. Layer 1: $(\sqrt{13}\times\sqrt{13})\,R\,13.9^\circ$, Layer 2: $(\sqrt{19}\times\sqrt{19})\,R\,23.4^\circ$

How to get the elements of the transformation matrices from this information?

I read in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/help-understanding-square-root-notation-of-supercell) that $(\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{3})\,R\,30^\circ$ corresponds to the rotation matrix $$\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}$$

However, it is not explained in that answer, how these matrix elements are obtained.

How to get rotation matrix in general case from root integer notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## $\sqrt{3}$ Case

$ \left( \sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}\right)R30$ is a short way of representing a supercell in Woods notation ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction#Notation_of_reconstructions), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlayer#Wood%27s_notation)), which essentially means that each of the basis vectors of the supercell are $\sqrt{3}$  times the magnitude of that of the primitive cell.

Woods Notation is given by: X(hkl) m × n - Rφ.

Here m and n are both $\sqrt{3}$, φ=30°

Now let us look at the $ \left( \sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}\right)R30$ supercell from the answer with some annotations that I added.

Here a1, a2 are the basis vectors of the primitive cell marked in green.

And b1, b2 are the basis vectors of the supercell marked in purple.

[image]

So from the image you can see that, to calculate b1, from the triangle law of vectors we first need to traverse 2 units of a1 and then 1 unit of a2.
Corresponding to [2 1 0], the first line of matrix.

Similarly, to calculate b2, we need to traverse negative 1 unit in a1 and 1 unit in a2.
Corresponding to [-1 1 0], the second line of matrix.

The additional row and column are introduced to represent a 3D rotation matrix, where the third dimension remains unaffected. In this case, the third row and column are [0, 0, 1], indicating that the z-axis remains the same.

Thereby, this gives us the transformation matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 0\\-1 & 1& 0 \\0 & 0& 1\end{bmatrix}

## Generic Case

Let b1/a1= m, b2/a2=n as per the Woods notation.

Let us assume |a1|=|a2|=1 since we start with unit cell.

Let $G_{11}, G_{12}, G_{21}, and \space G_{22}$ be the factors that a1 and a2 are multiplied in the Matrix form of Woods notation to obtain b1 and b2.

That is,

$b_{1} = G_{11}*a_{1} + G_{12}*a_{2}$

$b_{2} = G_{21}*a_{1} + G_{22}*a_{2}$

Therefore by Cosine law of triangles we have:

$m^2 = G_{11}^2+ G_{12}^2 - 2*G_{11}*G_{12}*cos(φ)$

$n^2 = G_{21}^2+ G_{22}^2 - 2*G_{21}*G_{22}*cos(φ)$

In above equations, we know m,n and φ. So we can solve the equations to obtain relationships between $G_{11} and G_{12}$ and
$ G_{21} and \space G_{22}$ with that we construct the transformation matrix like:
\begin{bmatrix} G_{11} & G_{12} & 0\\G_{21} & G_{22}& 0 \\0 & 0& 1\end{bmatrix}

For example, in the $\sqrt{3}$ case, since m and n are the same it would result in same equation for both rows of the matrix.
Observe the triangle with the φ, we would get:

$\sqrt(3)^2 = G_{11}^2+ G_{12}^2 - 2*G_{11}*G_{12}*cos(90-φ)$
Here we take 90-φ because, we need angle between the two lines with known values in this case 2 and 1.

Solving the equation of this ellipse would give us many possible sets of solutions:

$G_{11} = -2, G_{12} = -1$

$G_{11} = -1, G_{12} = -2$

$G_{11} = -1, G_{12} = 1$

$G_{11} = 1, G_{12} = -1$

$G_{11} = 1, G_{12} = 2$

and similarly for G21, and G22.

This calculation is shown in Wolfram Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a**2%2Bb**2-ab+%3D+3)

So similarly we can solve for any m,n and φ combination.